# Getting payment and payer id dynamically in django using python Paypal REST SDK

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal

I am new to django and python.
I am developing a website where i am using Paypal for transaction. I have successfully integrated python Paypal REST SDK with my project. Here is my `views.py` with the integration.

```
def subscribe_plan(request):

    exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.POST['subscribe'])
    exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
    exp_date = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)
    plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.POST['subscribe'])
    subs_plan = SubscribePlan(plan = plan,user = request.user,expiriary_date = exp_date)
    subs_plan.save()




    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    paypalrestsdk.configure({
      "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
      "client_id": "AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd",
      "client_secret": "EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX" })

    payment = Payment({
        "intent":  "sale",
        # ###Payer
        # A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
        # Payment Method as 'paypal'
        "payer":  {                                              
        "payment_method":  "paypal" },
        # ###Redirect URLs
        "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "www.mydomain.com/execute",
        "cancel_url": "www.mydomain.com/cancel" },
        # ###Transaction
        # A transaction defines the contract of a
        # payment - what is the payment for and who
        # is fulfilling it.
        "transactions":  [ {
        # ### ItemList
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": exact_plan.plan,
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "5.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1 }]},
        "amount":  {
              "total":  "5.00",
              "currency":  "USD" },
        "description":  "This is the payment transaction description." } ] }   )




selected_plan = request.POST['subscribe']
context = RequestContext(request)

if payment.create():

    print("Payment %s created successfully"%payment.id)

    for link in payment.links:#Payer that funds a payment
        if link.method=="REDIRECT":
            redirect_url=link.href
            ctx_dict = {'selected_plan':selected_plan,"payment":payment}
            print("Redirect for approval: %s"%redirect_url)
            return redirect(redirect_url,context)
else:                             
    print("Error %s"%payment.error)
    ctx_dict = {'selected_plan':selected_plan,"payment":payment}
    return render_to_response('photo/fail.html',ctx_dict,context)
```

Here in the payment dictionary ***www.mydomain.com/execute*** is given as return url and ***www.mydomain.com/cancel*** given as a cancel url.
Now for that return url and cancel url I have to make a another view which is given below.

```
def payment_execute(request):
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# ID of the payment. This ID is provided when creating payment.
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("PAY-57363176S1057143SKE2HO3A")
ctx = {'payment':payment}
context = RequestContext(request)

# PayerID is required to approve the payment.
if payment.execute({"payer_id": "DUFRQ8GWYMJXC" }):  # return True or False
  print("Payment[%s] execute successfully"%(payment.id))
  return render_to_response('photo/execute.html',ctx,context)


else:
  print(payment.error)
  return render_to_response('photo/dismiss.html',ctx,context)
```

You can see here in the payment_execute view, I have put static ***payment id*** and static ***payer id***. With this  ***static*** payment id and payer id, I have successfully completed one single payment using Paypal. But this ***payment id*** and ***payer id*** must be ***Dynamic***. How can i ***dynamically*** set the ***payment id*** and ***payer id*** in the payment_execute view. I have saved the payment id in the user session(in my subscribe_plan view) and I know that the payer id is supplied in the ***return url*** but I don't know how to fetch them because of my lack of knowledge. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @zogo, how are you passing csrf_token from Django template with this PayPal request? I have stuck on that, can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. payment id : In subscribe view, save the payment id

   request.session["payment_id"] = payment.id

   Later in payment_execute view, get the payment id :

   payment_id = request.session["payment_id"]

   payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)
2. payer id :

   It seems that you are already aware that the payer id is a parameter supplied in the return url.
   In your payment_execute view, you should be able to access the payer id by using:

   request.GET.get("PayerID")

The following links should be helpful for trying it out more and detailed documentaion:

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/python?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from Avi Das, I managed to get this information using POST instead of GET:

```
class PaypalExecutePayment:

    def __call__(self, request):
        payer_id = request.POST.get("payerID")
        payment_id = request.POST.get("paymentID")

        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(payment_id)

        if payment.execute({"payer_id": payer_id}):
            print("Payment execute successfully")
        else:
            print(payment.error)  # Error Hash
```

Connecting the class to my api:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url('^api/execute-payment/', csrf_exempt(views.PaypalExecutePayment())),
    ... 
]
```